# Switch two values using Search&Replace in TextMate2?

Tags: textmate, textmate2

I often have to switch two values in TextMate.

Original text:

```
@person = company.person
```

Needed text:

```
@company = person.company
```

What's the easiest way to do this using Search&Replace?

Thank you.

Comment: Addition: An easy (but a bit tedious) way is to replace "person" with "xxx", then replace "company" with "person", then replace "xxx" with "company".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a simple string search and replace; that is

> Search for: `@person = company.person`
>
> Replace with: `@company = person.company`

If you want to do something slightly more general (`@A = B.A` to `@B = A.B` for any `A` and `B`), then I would turn to regular expressions:

> Search for: `[@](.*) ?= ?(.*)\.\1`
>
> Replace with: `@$2 = $1.$2`

That will swap all pairs of the form `@A = B.A` to `@B = A.B` (regardless of spacing around the `=`). Make sure that the regular expressions box is ticked in the Find & Replace window.

If you only want to switch any pairs that begin with `@person` or `@company`, but not anything else, then the following will do it:

> Search for: `[@](person||company) ?= ?(.*)\.\1`
>
> Replace with: `@$2 = $1.$2`

Add more terms using the regex “or” operator, `||`. You can do the same for the second value. For example, if you wanted to match only items like `manager.` or `resources.`, then you’d use:

> Search for: `[@](.*) ?= ?(manager||resources)\.\1`
>
> Replace with: `@$2 = $1.$2`

Comment: Thanks, this is very explanatory. Still, it seems a bit difficult to me. It doesn't look easier than my "old way" (replace person with xxx, replace company with person, replace xxx with company). Regexes are unbelievably powerful, but they are definitely not easy to learn.